# How to start and stop EC2 instance using Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to start and stop an EC2 windows instance using lambda, i am using Node.js 8.10 to write the start and stop script.When i am testing the script the script is executed successfully but the EC2 instance is not effected.I am giving the instance details and script below

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event) => {

const ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ region: event.instanceRegion });
 ec2.stopInstances({ InstanceIds: [event.instanceId] }).promise()
    .then(() => callback(null, `Successfully stopped ${event.instanceId}`))
    .catch(err => callback(err));
};
```

The script executed successfully

[image]

Below is the instance details 
[image]

This is stop script but this is not able to stop the instance , please help me i am new to aws . Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to return `ec2.stopInstances()` promise. The way you are doing you are returning a resolved promise to handler and then you `.stopInstances()` doesnt finish its work

Comment: @guijob can you please edit my code , i am new to node also

Answer (score 5):

When using Lambda, your handler function receives three parameters: event, context and callback. You make use of `callback` when using synchronous functions. When using async you should return a promise.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

const ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ region: event.instanceRegion });
 return ec2.stopInstances({ InstanceIds: [event.instanceId] }).promise()
    .then(() => `Successfully stopped ${event.instanceId}`)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

In fact, when you use `async` keyword you are actually returning a promise, but by returning nothing, you are resolving it with `null` as response, so your code will just terminate and your `stopInstances` will not finish their work.

Comment: Or simply `await ec2.stopInstances({ InstanceIds: [event.instanceId] }).promise()`

Comment: exactly, there are a plenty of different solutions for this

Comment: not sure I agree the `.then().catch()` approach can be called a "solution". It doesn't make sense anymore once we have `async/await`. It certainly works but should be frowned upon.